# Getting the integer value of a ncurses chtype or unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to get the integer value of ncurses alternative character sheet characters.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint i = ACS_S7; //I've also tried other values
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

just prints `0` though.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps you forgot to call `initscr()` or made some other mistake

Comment: I needed to call initscr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you didn't call `initscr()` . This must be called before doing anything else in ncurses.

In this case, `ACS_S7` is a macro that refers to a static array, and part of the `initscr()` setup fills in that array based on the current locale etc.